# PDF to HTML conversion with accessible mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, math-software, online-resources

I am mainly searching for resources online for studying mathematics, however I am a visually impaired student taking a Calculus course in comunity college. I notice that most resources are in PDF format, and not everything seems to be in HTML format (I have found quite a few). I am aware of MathPix, but even that has limits on how many pages and snips can be done. So, I thought to ask here. Is there a converter that will take a PDF with math content and turn it into an HTML document (or a set of HTML documents) with correctly formatted mathematics for a screen reader user to navigate without the limitations of MathPix's education plan? I am specifically looking for free conversion, if possible.

Comment: This is an important question relevant for every mathematician or math student using assistive technologies. So even though it is maybe more suitable for a different site (maybe https://academia.stackexchange.com/ ? ) I hope that it doesn't get closed and receives a good answer.

Comment: Very unlikely without the source of the document available IMO. There are tools like pandoc that can convert from tex source to HTML while preserving some semantics, but I know of nothing that can get mathematical formatting out of a PDF like OCR does for text. If the text is not in the document (which is common for scans) the picture is even more gloomy.

Comment: I will ask there, thanks.

Comment: You say you are visually impaired. Please explain why and how you, because of this, prefer html  over pdf?

Comment: I require HTML format because PDFs never have properly formatted mathematics for a screen reader to navigate (with both speech and braille). Unless there is a way to render MathJax or MathML in PDF documents, I don't think that will work.

Comment: A Google search for "pdf to html converter" lists a few free converters. Did you find none of those to your liking?

Comment: I will do some testing when I have time. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most of the PDF's are generated from LaTeX an alternative to converting the PDF's to HTML can be to ask the writer if (s)he can produce HTML for you, or send you the source so that you can do it.

A tool for producing HTML from LaTeX: https://tug.org/tex4ht/

Answer (score 1):

Not the official text for your course, but perhaps useful:
Active Calculus is different from most existing calculus texts in at least the following ways: the text is freely readable online in HTML format ...

https://activecalculus.org/

Reading mathematics from pdf:

https://www.perkins.org/resource/how-read-math-expressions-screen-reader-windows-computer/

https://www.abdn.ac.uk/it/documents/Reading_PDFs_with_NVDA.pdf